# Tap & Go setup missed installed apps

Tags: cyanogenmod, 5.0-lollipop, nexus-4, 5.1-lollipop, oneplus-one

I have just executed a Tap & Go setup moving from Nexus 4 (Android 5.1.1) to OnePlus One (Android 5.0.2). It seems to be working all fine except for the fact that the setup misses the majority of apps installed on the Nexus 4.

**Update**: Followed TurboFools suggestion. Turns out that restoration is not using the device from the NFC connection. In fact, I missed the new lollipop  restoration process on my first try now the new device only restores from its own backup.  I am using the proper account. My other devices do not even show up as alternative options. Removing the new device from menu  in the play store did not help.

Am I lost?

Any idea how to restore from the other (Nexus 4) device?

Answer (score 1):

Seems as of today, it is not possible to restore a 5.1 lollipop backup to a 5.0 device. :(

[Backups not showing up for the restore process in Lollipop](https://productforums.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/nexus/cy6DoHSbDmA)

Latest CM 12.1 snapshots (Android 5.1) seem to do the trick. I personally decided to skip the restoration and do it manually.

Answer (score 0):

I've had hit or miss luck with this myself. I've had MUCH better results by skipping tap-and-go, causing it to let me pick from a list of previous devices, showing the date they were last used, and then allows me to view the entire list of apps it will download and individually uncheck the ones I don't want, or deselect all and then select the few I do. More granular and seems more reliable.

Comment: Followed your suggestion. Turns out that restoration is not using the device from the NFC connection.  In fact, I missed the new lollipop  restoration process on my first try now the new device only restores from its own backup.  My other devices do not even show up as alternative options. Removing the new device from menu  in the play store did not help.

Comment: Maybe try disabling and re-enabling the backup function on your Nexus 4 and downloading any app to it to try to trigger it in the system and then try again. The OnePlusOne may have overwritten it somehow.

Comment: Thanks  for you suggestions. Turned out that today, it does not seem possible to restore a 5.1 backup to a 5.0 device. You might want to check the link in  my answer.

Comment: Good to know. I've never stepped backwards, so didn't run into that.